# how to read a date into a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, date, struct

I have a csv data, it contains this structure :

```
2345678 Meier   Hans    12.10.1985  2.4
int, char[],char[], date,float
```

I want to make a struct from this line with those data types and I have to put the struct into an array, now when I come to read the date , what variable type should I use in the struct? and how can I read in the single day , month and year numbers into my type ?  is there a split function that splits at every dot (".") ?
should I use "struct tm ts" and assignt the day month and year to the ts.constants ? (ts_mday; ts_mmonth etc..)

what I did so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct studentendaten {
        int matrnr;
        char[] name;
        char[] vorname;     
        struct tm ts;           
        ts.tm_mday; 
        ts.tm_mon;
        ts.tm_year; 
        float note;
    }


  FILE * pFile;
  int ch;  
  int n = 0;
  pFile=fopen("studentendaten.txt","r");  
  if (pFile==nullptr) perror ("Error opening file");
  else
  {       
    while (ch != EOF) 
    {
      ch = fgetc (pFile);
      if (ch == ';') {n++;}
      putchar(ch);
    }   
    fclose (pFile);
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would work on getting the syntax errors out of your existing code before going on to the more meaty issues. The compiler is pretty good at telling you where they are.

Comment: For converting date/time "strings" into a binary structure you might like to have look at the `strptime()` function.

Comment: Are you saying that your **comma**-separated-value file contains no commas?

Answer (score 2):

You could use strptime() to parse the date string and store it in a tm struct. The tm struct contains fields for day, month and year. Have in mind that the day of the month counts from 0 to 11 and the year starts from 1900. Use strftime() to convert the tm struct back to a string.

Example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
  struct tm ts;

  if( argc > 1 )
  {
    memset( &ts, '\0', sizeof( ts ) );

    const char* cp = strptime( argv[1], "%d.%m.%Y", &ts );

    if( cp != NULL )
    {
      char buf[16];
      strftime( buf, sizeof( buf ), "%d.%m.%Y", &ts );
      printf( "%s\n", buf );
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now when I come to read the date, what variable type should I use in the struct?

I would use a class of type `std::tm`, the standard C class for dates.

> And how can I read in the single day, month and year numbers into my type?

This is the problem. There is no one standard way to interpret a date. Dates differ according to certain cultural-conventions. For this reason, the formatting, insertion and extraction of dates are typically delegated to the `time_put` and `time_get` facets of a locale.

You can incorporate this functionality into an extractor that not only checks for a valid stream state (because the insertion will be done using the concrete file stream classes, not `FILE`), but also ascertains the success of the operation. For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <ctime>

struct date // a simple date class
{
    std::tm ts;
};

template <class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is, date& d)
{
    if (!is.good())
        return is;

    std::ios_base::iostate err = std::ios_base::goodbit;
    try
    {
        typename std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>::sentry s(is);
        if (s)
        {
            std::istreambuf_iterator<CharT> o
                = std::use_facet<std::time_get<CharT,
                   std::istreambuf_iterator<CharT>>>(is.getloc()).get_date(
                    is, std::istreambuf_iterator<CharT>(), is, err, &d.ts);

            if (o != std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())
                err |= std::ios_base::failbit;
        } else
        {
            is.width(0);
            return is;
        }
    } catch(std::ios_base::failure&)
    {
        //  check the exception mask set the stream state
    }

    is.setstate(err);
    is.width(0);
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    date d;
    in >> d;
}
```

This is the extractor. The inserter should look somewhat similar, except that you would use `time_put` and `istreambuf_iterator`. You would also make sure to check for a failed insertion and set `badbit` if so.